# 2000 Honda Accord EX Brake light strange problem

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, old-cars

This has to be the strangest problem ever, 3 out of 4 of braking lights are not working during braking, but all lights are working with the key remote.

I did some research on internet, it turned out some automobile light bulb has multiple filaments, so I checked. Those bulbs seem to have a black build up on the glass. However, replacing the light bulbs does not fix this, when hitting the brake pedal, those 3 lights are still not on.

One thing worth mentioning is the 1 working brake light is perfectly responsive to braking pedal. So this ruled out the malfunction brake sensor. I looked up wiring diagram of this model. It clearly shows 4 brake lights controlled by a single switch in all variants.

Although maybe the light bulb can have multiple filaments, there are only 2 wires on each of them, + and - therefore there can't be any complication with the controls. Since the lights are on with remote, this is not the fuse or the relay or the control logic or broken connection or short or voltage etc, it is strange how to trace this problem on the rather straight forward system.

Comment: Can you add a link to the wiring diagram you found?

Comment: What do you mean by "all lights are working with the key remote"?  What is this remote?

Comment: Thank you for trusting us with your tail light issue! - First off, please post the wiring diagram as @HandyHowie requested. - Secondly, which light is out? ie is it the CMHSL? - Are you having any trouble with your turn signals? - Can you please go into more detail on what you mean by the one light "being responsive"? Please verify that it is the light that is otherwise not illuminating. To reply, simply edit your original post with the new information, we'll see it!